# Can I force putty to use some networking interface?

Tags: windows, ssh, routing, putty

The problem is that I've two networking interfaces one of them does not allow any outbound ssh connection.

How can I force putty to use the second network interface so I can connect to a remote host?

Do I have to alter the routing table?

Comment: Have you looked into ForceBindIP software? It is meant for situations like this.

Comment: no I did not. I'll try that!

Comment: `Do I have to alter the routing table?` Yes, very likely you do.